# Can't get location without opening google maps on android studio

Tags: java, android, google-location-services

Basically I noticed this weird reaction in the app, I get `location is null` however if I exit the app and open google earth map, request my location and re enter the app the location service will work just fine, any idea why this happens?

I am sure the issue is not on the Permission as I do check for this and it works completely fine, also the phones location are enabled which got me confused of why it reacts the way it does

```
  @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_customer,container,false);

        tableLayout = (TableLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.resultsTable);
        tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
//        tableLayout.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

//        Button searchNearby = v.findViewById(R.id.resultsTable);
//        searchNearby.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
//
//            }
//        });

        EditText editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtEditPostcodeSearch);
        Button clear = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnClearText);
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View av) {
                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

        if (checkGoogleServices()) {
            fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());
        }

        Button searchButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSearchCustomer);
        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText searchInput = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtEditPostcodeSearch);
                String search = searchInput.getText().toString();

                Log.d("SEARCH", search);

                if (searchInput.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please enter a search", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
                searchRequest.setTerm(search);
                getLocation();
            }
        });

        Button searchNearby = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnSearchNearby);
        searchNearby.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
                getLocation();
            }
        });
//
//        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.resultsTable);
//        tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
//
//        Button searchNearby = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearchNearby);
//        searchNearby.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
//                getLocation();
//            }
//        });


        return v;
    }

    protected boolean checkGoogleServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability ga = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int errorCode = ga.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getContext());
        if (errorCode != SUCCESS && ga.isUserResolvableError(errorCode)) {
//            ga.getErrorDialog(this, errorCode, 1000).show();
            Log.d("LOC", "ERROR with location services");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


private void getLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                            if (location != null) {
                                // Logic to handle location object

                                searchRequest.setLatitude(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                                searchRequest.setLongitude(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                                userLocation = location;
                                Log.d("lat", searchRequest.getLatitude());
                                Log.d("long", searchRequest.getLongitude());
                                doSearch();
                            } else {
                                Log.d("Location", "Location is null");
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            if (searchRequest != null && searchRequest.getTerm() != null) {
                                doSearch();
                            }
                        }
                    })
            ;
        } else {
            // You can directly ask for the permission.
            // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void doSearch() {
        View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        
        int rows = tableLayout.getChildCount();
        if (rows > 0) {
            tableLayout.removeViews(0, rows);
        }
        
        AppActivity a = (AppActivity) getActivity();

        CustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(a.getApplication());
        customerRepository.search(searchRequest).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), customers -> {
                Log.d("Found", String.valueOf(customers.size()));
                if (customers.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No results found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    TableRow[] tableRows = new TableRow[customers.size()];
                    // calculate distance of each customer from user
                    for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
                        Customer customer = customers.get(i);
                        try {
                            Location customerLocation = new Location("customer");
                            customerLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(customer.getLatitude()));
                            customerLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(customer.getLongitude()));
                            customer.setDistance(userLocation.distanceTo(customerLocation)*0.000621371f); // convert metres to miles
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            customer.setDistance(0);
                        }
                    }
                    // sort by distance ascending
                    customers.sort((c,d) -> {
                        if (c.getDistance() < d.getDistance()) {
                            return -1;
                        } else if (c.getDistance() > d.getDistance()) {
                            return 1;
                        } else {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    });
                    for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
                        tableRows[i] = new TableRow(getContext());
                        tableRows[i].setId(i + 1);
                        tableRows[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        ));
                        tableRows[i].setPadding(0, 20, 80, 20);
                        tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
                        tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_outline);

                        TextView customerText = new TextView(getContext());
                        customerText.setId(i + 111);
                        customerText.setText(customers.get(i).getName());
                        customerText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        customerText.setPadding(14, 5, 5, 5);
                        customerText.setTextSize(16);
                        customerText.setMaxLines(3);
                        customerText.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        customerText.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                        customerText.setWidth(200);

                        TextView text2 = new TextView(getContext());
                        text2.setId(i + 1111);
                        text2.setText(customers.get(i).getTown());
                        text2.setEms(4);
                        text2.setMaxLines(1);
                        text2.setTextSize(16);
                        text2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        text2.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        text2.setPadding(40, 5, 5, 5);

                        TextView text3 = new TextView(getContext());
                        text3.setId(i + 11111);
                        text3.setText(customers.get(i).getType());
                        text3.setEms(4);
                        text3.setMaxLines(1);
                        text3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        text3.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        text3.setTextSize(16);
                        text3.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

                        TextView text4 = new TextView(getContext());
                        text4.setId(i + 111111);
                        text4.setText(String.valueOf(customers.get(i).getDistance()));
                        text4.setEms(6);
                        text4.setMaxLines(2);
                        text4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        text4.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        text4.setTextSize(16);
                        text4.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

                        tableRows[i].addView(customerText);
                        tableRows[i].addView(text2);
                        tableRows[i].addView(text3);
                        tableRows[i].addView(text4);
                        tableLayout.addView(tableRows[i], new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        ));

                        tableRows[i].setClickable(true);
                        String customerId = customers.get(i).getUuid().toString();
                        int finalI = i;
                        tableRows[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                TableRow tr = (TableRow) view;
                                TextView s = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(0);
                                String r = s.getText().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                Fragment addAppointmentWithExistingCustomerActivity = new AddAppointmentWithExistingCustomerFragment();
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                                Bundle addBundle = new Bundle();
                                addBundle.putString(CUSTOMER_ID, customerId);
                                addAppointmentWithExistingCustomerActivity.setArguments(addBundle);

                                // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                                // and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
                                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, addAppointmentWithExistingCustomerActivity);
                                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                                // Commit the transaction
                                transaction.commit();

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `getLastLocation()` does not guarantee getting a location. If you are expecting a location, use other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply rely on **Last Location** because it may be null...

Instead of completely relying on Last Location you can `request location updates` whenever your last location is null and **stop the location update** once you get the location (stop the updates only if you want location once)

https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates

Answer (score 0):

```
if you want to access location even if the app is not in foreground ,you need to set "Allow all time" in location permission settings.Also include below line in AndroidManifest file.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```